# Calculating the odds of winning a card game

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics

So my friend made this game and I want to the odds of winning his game. So his game is basically I pay \$$1$ to draw $2$ cards from the deck and guess $2$ numbers and one suit. For each correct guess I get \$$1$. Doubled guesses still only count for one correct guess. So either I lose \$$1$ ($0$ correct guess), break even ($1$ correct guess), profit \$$1$ ($2$ correct guesses) or profit \$$2$ ($3$ correct guesses).

To win, I have to profit at least \$$1$ so that means I need to be able to guess either both numbers, or one number and one suit.

I was wondering what my odds of winning are or what the odds of all possibilities are.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the probability of each event and then use the [expected value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).

Comment: How would I do that? Like if I draw 2 cards and I need at least 2 guesses right would it be (2/13)*(1/4)*2? The 2/13 is the 2 numbers I chose out of the 13 possibilities, 1/4 is the suit and the last 2 is because there are 2 cards

Comment: Sorry I misread the question. I'm answering the question : how much do you win/lose on average. I will delete my answer if you think it's not valid.

Comment: Well, it's fine, since if I calculate the probability of each event, I'd be calculating my odds of winning. But I don't know how to calculate the probability of getting 2 guess or 3 guesses right. That's only problem I have